# Vue2: Duplicate Events Fired Due to Mixin

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

### Problem

An event is triggered in one section component and each sibling component triggers the same event.

In other words, if the call object is modified inside the customer section, the `syncCall` method fires twice. Once because of the customer section and once because of the pricing section.

---

### Context

The call component implements each of the section components, like so.

**Call.vue (Parent)**

```
<template>
  <customer-section
    :callObject="call"
    @change.self="syncCall">
  </customer-section>

  <pricing-section
    :callObject="call"
    @change.self="syncCall">
  </pricing-section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    CustomerSection,
    PricingSection
  },

  data () {
    return {
      call: {
        // ...
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    // ---
    // If a change event happens in one of the child
    // components, the same event is fired for
    // each child that shares the mixin.
    // ---
    syncCall (call) {
      console.warn('syncCall', call);

      this.$set(this.call, call);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This `call_section` mixin shares functionality between the section components.

**call_section.js**

```
let CallSectionMixin = {
  props: {
    callObject: { type: Object, required: true }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      call: this.callObject
    };
  },

  computed: {
    stringifiedCall () {
      return JSON.stringify(this.$data.call);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    stringifiedCall () {
      this.$emit('change', this.$data.call);
    }
  }
};

export default CallSectionMixin;
```

All My Children™.

**CustomerSection.vue**

```
import CallSectionMixin from './mixins/call_section';

export default {
  mixins: [CallSectionMixin]
};
```

**PricingSection.vue**

```
import CallSectionMixin from './mixins/call_section';

export default {
  mixins: [CallSectionMixin]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't due to the mixin. You're seeing the event fire twice because you are using the same `call` object for both child components. Whenever the `call` object changes, both components are firing the `change` event.

Either pass two separate objects to the child components or watch for changes to the `call` object at the parent level.

But also, it looks like you're just trying to keep the `callObject` properties in the two child components in sync. This is already taken care of with Vue's data-binding. Since both components are using the same `call` object, any changes in one will automatically update in the other.

Comment: I've updated the mixin to show the assignment `this.$data.call = this.callObject;`. Theoretically, each child should have its own copy of the object, but that doesn't seem to help.

I believe I am already listening at the parent level. Is there some other way that it might be implemented?

Comment: In javascript, when you assign an object to a variable, you effectively are setting a pointer to the object. So, even still, you are referencing the same object in both child components.

Comment: Your solution worked. I just didn't detect it because the previous logic was still cached.